# Some questions about the App Store review guidelines?

Tags: iphone, cordova, appstore-approval

I've made some iphone webapps before, using jQTouch and iUI but now i want to try out making a native Apps for iPhone. As i first step i thought of trying to port one of my webapps using Phonegap. So far it works well, but i'm a little concerned about some things in the [Apple Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) and wanted to see if anyone have prior experience and could answer som questions.

**2.5 Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected**

**2.6 Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected**

I'm not really sure what this means. I don't think they concern me but if anyone could give me som more info about it it would be nice.

**2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected**

This one is more tricky. Do they consider HTML code? What my app does is to load content into DIV-tags using jQuery.load()-function, that means much of the work in the app is performed on my server. Will it be "safer" if i generate JSON or XML of the data and process it with JavaScript inside the app instead of loading the formated HTML-code?

**2.12 Apps that are not very useful or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected**

This one together with the quote:

> If your App looks like it was cobbled together in a few days, or you're trying to get your first practice App into the store to impress your friends, please brace yourself for rejection. We have lots of serious developers who don't want their quality Apps to be surrounded by amateur hour.

Made me wonder what they consider a useful app and what lasting entertainment means. This is my first app and i dont aim for a broad audience, this is mostly a way to get to know the XCode, iPhone-development and the App Store review process before. However, the App will be really useful for me and a bunch of my friends.

Comment: Seems this question is more http://www.superuser.com material

Comment: This is not really a programming question, and I would recommend asking it on Apple's Developer Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple App Store policies, not about any particular programming problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.6 Don't specifically try to access files outside your app's Bundle or Documents directory and you should be fine.

2.7 Somewhere, it explicitly says you can download and use HTML/CSS/Javascript as long as you are running it inside an iOS UIWebView container.  But don't try to download, say, Lua source code at runtime and interpret it.

2.12 Don't waste the App store reviewer's time if you are just trying to "get to know" the app development or store distribution process.  Read about it instead.  Submit something only if you think there are people (not just your Mom) who will really want to download your app and not delete it after trying it out.  Maybe at least a dozen to hundred someones.  If not, distribute some Ad Hoc deployments to your buddys instead.

Comment: 2.7 Extreme interpretation:  I'm not sure how Apple would rule on a Lua (et.al.) interpreter completely implemented in Javascript running inside a UIWebView.